# Is CN/Hostname verification against SSL certificate required for non browser software using openssl & why?

Tags: tls, openssl, vulnerability

In presence of 'trust certificates' & other attributes .. how important is this?

Does OpenSSL implement it now & If not why does OpenSSL not implement?

This is between non browser client & server.

Comment: Nearly identical question in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138700/is-validation-of-cn-hostname-verification-against-ssl-certificate-required-in-op which is on hold and suggested for move here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to a server and the server returns a valid certificate, then you "know" (subject to the vagaries of PKI) that you have connected to a "valid" server, whose identity is contained in the certificate. However, there is more than one SSL server on this planet. You still have to decide whether the server you contacted is the one you *wanted* to talk to. That's what the name check means.

This is the distinction between *authentication* (verifying who you are talking to) and *authorization* (deciding whether who you are talking to is indeed who you should be talking to). You need both. If you remove the [name check](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) then you must implement some other mechanism which allows your client to distinguish between the genuine server, and some other server with another name.

Comment: I Think you misunderstood the question here. OP is asking if its important to check the hostname against the hostname specified while connecting. Thats not important. If you connect to lb.someserver.com and the certificate is vs.anotherserver.com and you in some way know that vs.anotherserver.com is the correct server (for example in a client configuration file), then it wont matter that it does not precisely match whats in DNS.

Comment: @Thomas Pornin, Could you explain how hostname checking works? What is the safe way to check hostname? I am not sure how we can be ensured that address X is X in fact.

Answer (score 2):

It is still just as important.  Even if I am Mr.BadHacker, I can get a trusted certificate saying that I am Mr.BadHacker.  If you are trying to connect to your office via SSH and you accept a trusted connection to Mr.BadHacker as being your office, then you are going to have problems.

Trust doesn't mean that the site is good, it simply means that they are who they say they are.  It is completely meaningless without also checking who they claim to be.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already said why it is important to check the identity (hostname).

As for the how with openssl: current releases (1.0.1) do not have the necessary checks so most users of openssl code their own (and often wrong) or omit the check (even worse).

In the code base planned for release 1.1 there is a function x509_check_host which should be better than no checks, but its implementation is wrong too (see OpenSSL ticket #3288).

Comment: It is explained well in this page:
https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR ...it depends, but hostname verification is **not** required by the TLS protocol. The reason for that is that it has been deferred to application level protocols that use TLS.

---

Hostname verification (or validation) is part of HTTP over TLS (i.e. HTTPS) protocol, see [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818.html#section-3.1):

> If the hostname is available, the client MUST check it against the
> server's identity as presented in the server's Certificate message,
> in order to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks

Furthermore, there is [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125.html) which specifies best practices on hostname verification.

TLS doesn't specify how PKI validation needs to happen at all, e.g. in [TLS 1.3:

> In general, detailed certificate validation procedures are out of
> scope for TLS (see [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)).  This section provides TLS-specific
> requirements.

But neither does X.509, as it mainly contains rules how the hostname should be represented and/or compared, e.g. in [section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-7.2) and [section 7.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-7.3).

---

However, there are are reasons why verifying the hostname is not necessary or feasible:

- It could be that you have an application that doesn't rely on DNS, but uses another way of authenticating an identity. This is for instance often te case for client certificates (client authentication is optional in TLS). You may e.g. have a personal certificate to login to a company domain.
- You may rely on certificate pinning, in which case the entity authentication has happened beforehand. Of course, that means that the trust has been established beforehand, and that might well have included hostname verification.
- You might have a PKI with a limited number of roots, where you trust each client to be secure, or where impersonation of one client isn't a security issue. In that case you might just accept any end-entity certificate. This is getting outside of normal usage of TLS though, as you are now skipping entity authentication within the protocol entirely.

---

Generally however, if you have a generic web-server then yes, I'd say that hostname verification is **very important**, because otherwise you would inherently trust **all other certificate / key pairs** on the internet - all servers that use TLS including ones that are generated specifically to attack your secure connection.

For machine-to-machine connections between servers that also means that it is important to perform hostname verification for the client server. If feasible it would also be a good idea to use a specific PKI with a proprietary trust store; for M2M you generally don't need to trust all the other machines on the internet after all.